# Poincare dual of a point

Tags: homology-cohomology

Why is the closed Poincare dual of a point in $R^n$ trivial but the compact  dual is a "bump"?

Please provide very detailed answer.

Comment: Please provide very detailed definition of "bump" - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/817302/poincare-dual-of-unit-circle).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let M be an oriented manifold. Recall that the closed Poincare dual of a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $M$ is an element in $H^{n-k}(M)$. In our case, as a point is $0$-dimensional and $H^n(\mathbb{R}^n)=0$, there is nothing to compute.

The compact dual should be some $\omega\in H_c^n(\mathbb{R}^n)$, such that for every closed $0$-form $\tau$ one has $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\omega\wedge\tau=\int_p\tau,$$where $p$ denotes our point. Since a closed $0$-form is in fact a *constant function*, this equality holds for $$\omega=fdx_1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx_n,$$where $f$ is a function with compact support whose integral is equal to $1$.

Comment: thanks but this means the integral is the constant, but is the integral a constant function over a single point not zero? The integral of constant function over a single point is zero that is. (the integral over a single point is zero unless we have a "delta" function)

Comment: The integral of a function on a point is equal to $\pm$ the value of the function at this point. If this function is a *closed* $0$-form, it is constant. If in addition it has a *compact support*, it is necessarily $\equiv0$.

Comment: thanks I think I now get it; the integral of a zero form which is always just a function is by *definition* the value of the function? For higher forms the integral over a point is always zero.

Comment: Note - you can't integrate other forms on points, because points are $0$-dimensional. The rank of the integrated form is always equal to the dimension of the manifold on which it is integrated.

Comment: right I see thanks